# QgsField : Undefined Variable

Tags: pyqgis, standalone

Im writing a stand alone app in Python using QGIS 2.01 on Ubuntu via Eclipse bindings.

I've written code which successfully adds features to a new in memory layer and displays, but now I want to add attributes. The following code is giving an error : "Undefined Variable: QgsField" error despight importing both "qgis.core *" and specifically QgsField.

```
import os
import os.path
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QMainWindow
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, Qt
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField, QgsMapLayerRegistry  
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant 

Graphiclayers =  QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values() 
        GraphLyr = Graphiclayers[0]

        pr = GraphLyr.dataProvider() 
        # add fields
        pr.startediting()
        pr.addAttributes([QqsField('Colour', QVariant.Int),
                          QgsField('QTriad', QVariant.Int),
                          QgsField('QBox', QVariant.Int)])
```

Comment: There is a typo in the first `QgsField`, which is written `QqsField`. This probably causes your error.

Comment: You better update to a newer version. QGIS 2.0 is nothing you want to build on today!

Comment: yeah.. its a personal project in my spare time so QGIS is progressing faster than my code.. hopefully it will upgrade without too many issues when complete, but one issue at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Ok then!)

There is a typo in the first `QgsField`, which is written `QqsField`. This probably causes your error.

Comment: Just one of those cases where you stare too long at a problem! thanks for the swift response, saved me allot more staring...